# JavaScript: get text from a properties-file

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, properties-file

I have this JavaScript function:

```
function changeMessage() {

    var msgDiv = $("body").find("#openChangeMsgDiv");
    var msgSpanOut = $("body").find("#openChangeMsgSpan");
    var msgIcon = $("body").find("#openChangeMsgGlyphicon");
    var msgSpanText = $("body").find("#openChangeMsgText");
    var msgText = "PROBLEM";

    if($("#resetMessage").val() == "true") {
        msgDiv.addClass("pull-right col-xs-8");
        msgSpanOut.addClass("errorMsg");
        msgIcon.addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign msgSign");
        msgSpanText.text(msgText);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

At this point I write the text "PROBLEM" in my span-element "msgSpanText". I define this text in my JavaScript. I would like to get the text, which I want to add to the span-element, out of a properties-file like

```
message.changes.open=NEW TEXT HERE
```

instead out of the JavaScript. Is it possible to mention `message.changes.open` in my JS function and get the text `NEW TEXT HERE`?

I hope it is clear what I want to do ;-)
Thanks!!

Comment: You want to change the text of your Span Text by doing: `messages.changes.open='NEW TEXT HERE'`?

Comment: I have two files: `file.js` and `file.properties`. I want only change the properties-file, if the text changes. `message.changes.open=NEW TEXT HERE` is part of the properties-file. JavaScript should "read" the text out of the properties-file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you must first load the file.properties file into the browser (if it's javascript it's no problem). Then simply modify this line:

```
var msgText = "PROBLEM";
```

With:

```
var msgText = messages.changes.open;
```

I however, i'm very wary of programming this way as the file inclusion is necessary.

Comment: Usually the data of the properties-file are read from a Java method. However in this specific case I need JavaScript to read these data, because a dynamic functionality is needed. Is there a possibility to use JavaScript to read out the properties-file via Java so that I do not need to load the properties-file into the browser? Thanks for your helping hand!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. In fact, I'm strongly against it. What you are trying to do is to have Java parse out the file and serve it through Java. When it really should be served statically. If you must do it this way, then you must have Java print Javascript code directly into the HTML code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far! Just one last question: How do I load a file into the browser, so that JavaScript can work with it?

Comment: You add a script tag. `<script src="yourJavascriptFile.js"></script>`